# Can I define a "rec" function in another "rec" function in Ocaml?

Tags: function, recursion, ocaml

I must make a function `isFunction` that takes a list of couples as an argument and return true if there is no repetition considering the first element in each couple and false if there is a repetition.

For example :`isFunction [(1,3);(2,40);(3,40)]` returns `true` but `isFunction [(1,3);(2,40);(1,40)]` returns `false` because 1 is repeated.

For now, my code is :

```
let rec exist e = function
    |[] -> false
    |(a,_)::l -> e=a || exist e l;;
let rec isFunction = function
    |[]->true
    |(a,_)::l -> not(exist a l) && isFunction l;;
```

which works perfectly! But the question is : is there another way to define `isFunction` without defining another auxiliary function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `exist` as local to `isFunction`:

```
let rec isFunction l =
  let rec exist e = function
    |[] -> false
    |(a,_)::l -> e=a || exist e l
  in
  match l with
   |[]->true
   |(a,_)::l -> not(exist a l) && isFunction l
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use List.exists :

```
let isFunction = function
  | []        -> true
  | (a,_)::tl -> not (List.exists (fun (a',_) -> a'=a) tl) && isFunction l;;
```